# Weblogic log customization

Tags: logging, weblogic, customization, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have a weblogic server (10.3.5).
I have configured a new logger/log_handler, no problem.

I now want to change, on this log_handler, the way the log are written.
For the moment, it is written this way :

```
[2013-07-29T09:41:16.653+00:00] [MS_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [myCustomLogger] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: Anonymous] [ecid: 3928459900541890,0:1:1:1] [APP: myfrontend-1] [URI: /FO/app/pages/feedback] My loggued message.
```

I need to remove all the part weblogic automatically add to finally get :

```
My loggued message.
```

My `logging.xml` contains  :

```
<log_handler name='myCustomLLog-handler' class='oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ODLHandlerFactory' filter='oracle.dfw.incident.IncidentDetectionLogFilter'>
   <property name='path' value='${domain.home}/servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}-myCustomLog.log'/>
   <property name='maxFileSize' value='10485760'/>
   <property name='maxLogSize' value='104857600'/>
   <property name='encoding' value='UTF-8'/>
   <property name='useThreadName' value='true'/>
   <property name='supplementalAttributes' value='J2EE_APP.name,J2EE_MODULE.name,WEBSERVICE.name,WEBSERVICE_PORT.name,composite_instance_id,component_instance_id,composite_name,component_name'/>
</log_handler>
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: do you need to customize the access log ?

Comment: No, just the "normal" wbelogic logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question to Oracle teams, they said it is not possible, except by using log4j logger.

Quotting BeeAarKay :

> To my knowledge, you can't change WebLogic Server's own Log Message
>   Format (any ways the support requires informations in case of a
>   problem).
>
> But you can configure WebLogic to use Log4j (please review the URL :: 
>   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/logging/config_logs.html#wp1014610
>   for "How to Use Log4j with WebLogic Logging Services") and, when Log4j
>   is enabled, you can get a reference to the org.apache.log4j.Logger
>   that the server is using and attach your own appender.
>
> When Log4j is enabled, you get a reference to the
>   org.apache.log4j.Logger that the server is using from the
>   weblogic.logging.log4j.Log4jLoggingHelper class.
>
> With a Log4j Logger reference, `you can attach you own custom appender
>   to receive the server log events; for example, you might attach an
>   appender that sends the server log events to Syslog or the Windows
>   Event Viewer. Additionally, you can use the Logger reference to issue
>   log requests to WebLogic logging services; this requires that the
>   Log4j libraries be available to your deployed application.
>
> But this is not a replacement of WebLogic's own log.